# Consecutive records having same timestamp - AWS Lambda, DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I have a Node.js Lambda function that inserts records into DynamoDB. While inserting, I am marking the records with a timestamp under a field called `createdAt` using the `new Date().getTime()` method like this:

```
const timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
```

Then inside the lambda :

```
const data = {
    ...JSON.parse(event.body),
    purchased: false,
    _id: uuid.v4(),
    createdAt: timestamp,
    updatedAt: timestamp,
};
```

While retrieving the data, I'm performing a scan operation then manually sorting the returned array of records using the JS array sort method to order the results in descending order of `createdAt` (ie, latest record should appear at the top):

```
    //sort data in descending order of createdAt
    data = data.sort((a, b) => {
        let aDate = Number(a.createdAt);
        let bDate = Number(b.createdAt);

        return bDate - aDate;
    });
```

Now this works fine while I'm testing in localhost, but while executing the code on AWS Lambda I noticed a strange issue -  **multiple records created seconds apart from each other had the same timestamp!** This affected the sorting of the records and returned an unsorted randomly ordered list. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
[image: Records returned from the lambda function - Notice the same timestamp on all records!]

Comment: Just to be certain - you create the `timestamp` value inside the lambda function, and not outside it?

Comment: Outside. Oh I get it!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was creating the `timestamp` outside the lambda function. This meant that the `timestamp` variable was getting reused as the instance of the funcion was being retained to serve subsequent requests (the same reason why it is advised to create database connections outside the lambda). That's why same timstamps were being observed on multiple records created just seconds apart.

Thanks to [August](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26051/august-lilleaas) and [Alfarhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7969717/alfarhan-zahedi) for pointint it out!

The solution -  **create the timestamp inside the lambda function**.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString();
    const data = {
        ...JSON.parse(event.body),
        purchased: false,
        _id: uuid.v4(),
        createdAt: timestamp,
        updatedAt: timestamp,
    };
// rest of the code goes here.....

};
```

Comment: Should have added this as an answer instead of a comment, glad you got it sorted out!